# Any shortcut to auto-fill the word under the cursor for "Find in Path" in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When I press Ctrl+Shift+F in JetBrains IDE, I can use "Find in Path" function, but the searching word is empty or the word which is previously typed is filled.
I would like to fill the searching word by the word under the cursor automatically.

Is possible to auto-fill the word under the cursor for "Find in Path" in JetBrains IDE?

Comment: Just select the text in Editor before hitting `Ctrl+Shift+F` -- IDE will auto-insert that text into the search field.

Comment: Manually selecting the word before start search text is a very annoying workaround. We have computers to simplify workflows. Why should we press multiple hotkeys if a single one could do the same?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use "Extend Selection" to select the word under the cursor and then use "Find in Path" which should be automatically with what was selected in the editor.

Comment: Manually selecting the word before start search text is a very annoying workaround. We have computers to simplify workflows. Why should we press multiple hotkeys if a single one could do the same?